# Checking whether a point is close to a triangle

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry

I am reading a paper on collision detection in cloth simulation, please  help me understanding following lines written in the paper :

To check if a point x4 is closer than some thickness h to a triangle
x1 x2 x3 with normal n we first check if the point is close to the plane
containing the triangle: **|x43 · n| < h**. If so, we project the point onto
the plane and compute the barycentric coordinates w1, w2, w3 with respect to the triangle x1 x2 x3.

If the barycentric coordinates are all within the **interval [−δ , 1 + δ ]**
where δ is h divided by a characteristic length of the triangle, the
point is close.

Please help me understanding 2nd paragraph, what does **characteristic length** of the triangle mean?

Comment: ''characteristic length'' stands for ''average size of your object''. The characteristic length of a building is its height. For a triangle, the longest side is a good approach, but there are many more.